# How to make a functional React component with generic type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics, tsx

I'm trying to make a React component which takes in a generic type parameter which will be part of its prop type.

I want a solution that would look something like this:

```
interface TestProps<T> {
  value: T;
  onChange: (newValue: T) => void;
}

const Test: React.FC<TestProps<T>> = (props) => (
  <span>{props.value}</span>
);
```

I have seen that there is support for this in TypeScript 2.9 and I'm on 4.3.5.

Usage of this would look like this:

```
const Usage: React.FC = () => (
  <div>
    <Test<Obj>
      value={{ name: 'test' }}
      onChange={(newValue) => {
        console.log(newValue.name);
      }}
    />
  </div>
);
```

Code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-playground-forked-8hu13?file=/src/index.tsx

Comment: Just without `React.FC` helper type: `function Test<T>(props: TestProps<T>) { ...` https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-typescript-playground-forked-lgnid?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The easiest way is to make the generic FC a regular function, not an arrow function. (`React.PropsWithChildren<>` emulates what `React.FC` does to your `props` type.)

```
function Test<T>(props: React.PropsWithChildren<TestProps<T>>) {
    return <span>Some component logic</span>;
}
```

Comment: I've been agonizing over this recently. This is fine and dandy however there's no explicit statement in the code that Test is in fact a `FC<TestProps<T>>` for some arbitrary type `T`. AAMOF my understanding is that this kind of statement cannot be expressed but I don't have a clear mental model as to where the limitation originates from. Is it a shortcoming of the TS type system, or of the particular way `FC` is defined in React?

Comment: you've missed something, `React.FC` does not only make sure the props are using type checking. but it also makes sure the return value of your function (function component) is valid, your function in the code above for example doesn't make sure of that

Answer (score 31):

You need to rewrite your `Test` component in this way

```js
const Test= <T,>(props:TestProps<T>) => (
    <span>Some component logic</span>
);
```

> Can you show the same with React.FC<TestProps>?
> It is impossible to do with `FC`.

This is `FC` implementation:

```js
interface FunctionComponent<P = {}> {
  (props: PropsWithChildren<P>, context?: any): ReactElement<any, any> | null;
  // ... other static properties
}
```

As you might have noticed, `FC` is a function type, not type of props.

**UPDATE**

You can create higher order function, but I'm not sure if it worth it

```js
const WithGeneric = <T,>(): React.FC<TestProps<T>> =>
  (props: TestProps<T>) => (
    <span>Some component logic</span>
  );
const Test = WithGeneric<Obj>()
```

Comment: Can you show the same with `React.FC<TestProps<T>>`?

Comment: Made an update. It is impossible with `FC`

Comment: Yes, FC is a function type, but the point of my question was that can you show a syntax that would allow annotating the generic arrow function with `React.FC` so it'd apply the same types (modified props, annotated return type, possible static additions).

Comment: I made an update. you can wrap your component in higher order function. It worth use `value` argument to infer `T` instead of explicit generic parameter without value but it is up to you

Comment: `react native`'s `Fast Refresh` did not work for that component. When the parent component is saved, it reloaded. Does anyone know why it doesn't work?

Comment: I think the HOL hack tortuous though it is, is the only way in TypeScript / React to explicitly assert in the code that a certain value is a `React.FC` for some generic `Props<T>`.

Comment: The trick is the `,`: `<T,>() => <div />`.

Answer (score 15):

In my case it was like the following codes:

```js
export interface FormProps<T> {
  validator?: AnyObjectSchema;
  onSubmit?: (data: T) => void;
}

const Form = <T = any,>({
  children,
  validator,
}: PropsWithChildren<FormProps<T>>): JSX.Element => {
  ~~~
```

And in usage:

```js
type MyType = ...

<Form<MyType>
  validation={something}
  onSubmit={handleSomething}
>
  <SomeCompo />
  <AnotherSomeCompo />
</Form>
```