# Properly typing a React Typescript FunctionComponent whose parameterized type also requires a type parameter

Tags: reactjs, typescript

There's probably an obvious answer to this, but I haven't been able to identify the right keywords to find it.

Suppose I have a type-parameterized `FooProps`, e.g.:

```js
type FooProps<T> = { ... bar: T, ...}
```

I'm building a `FunctionComponent` that should take a `FooProps` as its type parameter.

The following is not correct:

```js
const component: FunctionComponent<PropsWithChildren<FooProps<T>>> = <T, >(props: FooProps<T>) => {...}
```

because `cannot find name 'T'`.

However,

```js
const component: FunctionComponent<PropsWithChildren<FooProps>> = <T, >(props: FooProps<T>) => {...}
```

is not correct, because `Generic type 'FooProps' requires 1 type argument(s)`.

I can get away with just not annotating it, but the inferred type is then `<T>(props: FooProps<T>) => JSX.Element`, which wouldn't be so bad, except it means that I have to include the `children` member manually on `FooProps<T>`.

What is the correct way to annotate the type of this `FunctionComponent` when the type that satisfies its type parameter has its own parameterization?

---

Follow-on question:

Okay, so the first issue is that `component`'s `props` parameter is still declared as `FooProps<T>` rather than `PropsWithChildren<FooProps<T>>`. Correcting that gets me most of the way there. However, I'd still like to be a bit more explicit if I can.

So I can do:

```
const component: FunctionComponent<PropsWithChildren<FooProps<any>>> =
    <T, >(props: PropsWithChildren<FooProps<T>>) => {
```

but can't do:

```
const component: FunctionComponent<PropsWithChildren<FooProps<T>>> =
    <T, >(props: PropsWithChildren<FooProps<T>>) => {
```

Is there a way to do this explicitly so that the generic type can feed through all the way? In my particular use case, I don't actually use `T` directly in this component, so marking it `any` is fine, but it'd be nice to know I can be explicit if I need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perfectly fine to wrap your `FooProps` into `PropsWithChildren`:

```js
import React, { PropsWithChildren } from 'react'


type FooProps<T> = { bar: T, }

const Component = <T,>(props: PropsWithChildren<FooProps<T>>) => {
  return null

}

const foo = <Component bar={1}>123</Component>
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/w615vW)

Your example does not work because you are trying to mix argument inference with explicit type declaration up front.

If you want to use generics, you are not allowed to use explicit type anymore. Using explicit type disabling type inference. Further more, using explicit type) means that you know all your types up front.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68757395/how-to-make-a-functional-react-component-with-generic-type/68757498#68757498) answer might be useful

Comment: I was a little confused by "mix argument inference with explicit type declaration" then realized that I was still declaring `Props` as `T` rather than `PropsWithChildren<T>`. Annotating the component's props correctly will get me most of what I want, but I'm going to add a follow-on syntax question too. Thanks!