# How to pass a Generic type to a functional component props which also extends another Interface for its props?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics, next.js, react-hook-form

#### Explantion

I'm creating a dynamic input form using the FormProvider from react-hook-form.

```
const formMethods = useForm<TSongFormData>();
return (
    <FormProvider {...formMethods}>
       <SongInputForm />
    </FormProvider>
)
```

In the `SongInputForm` component I have my actual form which will have the input components which I have created for every `input elements`  like `input` `teaxtarea` and so on...

```
const SongForm = () => {
  const { handleSubmit } = useFormContext<TSongFormData>();
  return (
        <form
          onSubmit={handleSubmit((data) => console.log("data", data))}
        >
          <InputElement label="Song Name" name="name" />
          <InputElement label="Author" name="author" />
          <input type="submit" />
        </form>
    );
  };
}
```

The `InputElement`ccomponent would receive all the `props` for the `input` element itself and the `name` prop would be a union type `TSongFormDataKey` of all the keys of the form data.

```
interface ITextInputProps extends React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement> {
  label?: string;
  name: TSongFormDataKey;
}

const InputElement = ({ name, label, ...restProps }: ITextInputProps) => {
  const { register } = useFormContext<TSongFormData>();
  return (
    <div>
      <label htmlFor={name}>{label}</label>
      <input id={name} {...restProps} {...register(name)} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

#### Question

As of now, I have hardcoded the types `TSongFormData` and `TSongFormDataKey` in the `InputElement` component.
But how do I pass both the types `TSongFormData` and `TSongFormDataKey` as generics to the `InputElement` component so that I can make it dynamic and have more flexibility on the type of props passed to it??

What I'm looking for is something like this:

```
interface ITextInputProps<T> extends React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement> {
  label?: string;
  name: T;
}

const InputElement = <T,K>({ name, label, ...restProps }: ITextInputProps<T>) => {
  const { register } = useFormContext<K>();
  return (
    <div>
      <label htmlFor={name}>{label}</label>
      <input id={name} {...restProps} {...register(name)} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

where `T` would be `TSongFormData` and `K` would be `TSongFormDataKey`.

I've created a codesandbox if anyone wants to play with it:
https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-sanne-uz3ei8

I'm new to typescript and trying to get my head around generics, but finding it so hard.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: This post helped me a bit when working with genric type: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68757395/how-to-make-a-functional-react-component-with-generic-type
My question is rather why do you want to do this? Feels like it could be solved without generic types?

Comment: @Disco I'm trying to have a single ```InputElement``` component for all the forms I would have. So even if the form data structure changes, I can pass the type as generics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the `ITextInputProps` type generic and the `InputElement` name generic. For `name` we can use the `Path` generic type from `useFormContext`. `keyof T` would also work, except `register` expects a `Path<T>`, and while that will include `keyof T`, while `Path` still has unresolved type parameters (such as `T`) typescript won't be able to follow that relationship.

When you instantiate the component, you will have to specify the argument explicitly:  `<InputElement<TSongFormData> label="Song Name" name="name" />`

You can also create a specialized version of input field for a specific type using an instantiation expression in newer versions of TS:

```
const SongInputElement = InputElement<TSongFormData>
```

Putting it all together we get:

```
interface ITextInputProps<T> extends React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement> {
  label?: string;
  name: Path<T>;
}

const InputElement = <T extends FieldValues>({ name, label, ...restProps }: ITextInputProps<T>) => {
  const { register } = useFormContext<T>();
  return (
    <div>
      <label htmlFor={name}>{label}</label>
      <input id={name} {...restProps} {...register(name)} />
    </div>
  );
};



const SongForm = () => {
  const { watch, handleSubmit } = useFormContext<TSongFormData>();

  return (
    <InputElement<TSongFormData> label="Author" name="author" />
  );
};

const SongFormV2 = () => {  
  const { watch, handleSubmit } = useFormContext<TSongFormData>();
  const SongInputElement = InputElement<TSongFormData>
  return (
    <SongInputElement label="Song Name" name="name" />
  )
};
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQFCiSxwDecAYsFgDYAmAaspwCuWVABo4ABWQwAFuMGosraCADCEAHYwsAD3gBfOERJwARJTwwAtDIgQA1lYIrTAbho0A9J5SdOcWSw4MGIwdAgCFA04YA0wQXguLBAsLThcZGiAIyCwNEVuLx8NZBSjDh44VFtBSpyUOHssAE84CLgAFQBlTQBzZSgQABFpZDotLCgCPCCASQ7dGFm4hIlQ1AAeDoA+OEXU7nRsSwA6ZfiYAAkOgFkAGQBBGBgoYCyEkQ3r+-OEgFFOMlUjBdkwaHA4JxkDlOAB+ABcVResV67ghJRSiKksi223c+g8uE0qHgvxgAKBaQAvHAtns9Ad0OwuHwBMJUNsABQsDFYcRQmHiE7CygktYQMJwfSI+aLMnisK4gCUcCpoPB6WJ8BYlF6wBJkylqrgCiUKnUEz0uM5SrRcEoMEEUGinI1EI23GAADdtm6IbSBVw4DIYCBOAMqUxefptkxA5x9BtPPHff7-RtYhcYtxI9HmMKTqKYArUIYmAXdfrtFBObylYZPKn055PT6NbaaPp3B5dAx4DBmmAgt0+gNhqNjWD0aUsIiSa8NKiNcgErYoAikQulxDUEJehv5yi7bg1woD8jF3asq9uL0sOet3bOM1XrhUBuWCTMgAvZBzi+9FKADaAC6+LdkSGgknAPSLmOxo2qq6oQpB0EsAA7tIJ7iDImTcICXSCFkIDAAYxqmmOFraFaI5wSoIwwMgXIdhqDpOi6fobE2aYbM4gx+mmljAJoVKmKYAn+rgUKoKgAByM6ib0N5wEpwDcFYRKcKgVgAEwqcgYBWM0VgAGz6YZOhWAAHOJaZppohHEaRka4Ro+FYI5JEwJynLcKMKpqpqUEQICJycBAvScqYfmMaY4gxcgSr1hJ3F2RsZIUikWhbLB-T0aMuzxqJuVwPJKSmHAvKibyFWNhJ7oZYCWUwDlo75YxhXQlwokPKu0AVVVpgrrI-VwHVdnppmCQBIOWCiagRFebVqXup4fEgCttIhFgsYAFJdAA8rJJyHouwAEM0nKYTAJ42uIGi1Jw4g6fWSbbalSZNh2XaElqMFtYMvB6TSiGBVOQVoXA13YcGeEEYtpFGjSFHmpo1EtbReWDAxTE2sef25Y1lLwDSRPNa1dHYwVrFYI6zpwK6PGbbxKj1Sg+DCRoom2RN6TSXJCmmKp3AqTeGkhdpem9AZRmmeZViWTZbMOQjMAuXDHmqz5CUBbsqEhVgYURVFCVxXAOvJRNm3uoTKzkk1wKQl1nDFX0pUzgNgs1WN1u0rbFyZY7RWmL1I1QJ7KSicNa7LWzGZ2zNQ7zarscTUm63M+9TD7UdJ0Aedl3QzId2VY9z2vZ472ceNcDfa4QA)

Comment: man, you are the best!! Works flawlessly! I never knew the thing you mentioned about Path. Thanks a ton!