# Which syntax is correct for this generic TypeScript React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics, typescript-generics, react-typescript

My component should map through a list where all elements are same type. In props I give list and function which returns  JSX element

```
interface ListProps<T>{
    items: T[];
    renderItem: (item: T) => ReactNode;
}

const List = <T>(props: ListProps<T>) => {
    return (
        <div>
            {props.items.map(props.renderItem)}
        </div>
    );
};
```

I stacked with this functional component, how to write this generic `<T>` properly?

Comment: You'll have a better time with just `function List<T>(...)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a functional React component with generic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68757395/how-to-make-a-functional-react-component-with-generic-type)

Answer (score 0):

The following should work, note the `<T,>` with a comma. You can refer to [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45576880/1232796) for more information.

```
import * as React from 'react';

interface ListProps<T> {
    items: T[];
    renderItem: (item: T) => React.ReactNode;
}

const List = <T,>(props: ListProps<T>) => {
    return (
        <div>
            {props.items.map(props.renderItem)}
        </div>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create your type as follows

```
interface ListProps<T> {
  items: T[];
  renderItem: (item: T) => ReactNode;
}

const List: <T>(props: ListProps<T>) => ReactNode = props => {
  return <div>{props.items.map(props.renderItem)}</div>;
};
```

Or if you choose to use function

```
interface ListProps<T> {
  items: T[];
  renderItem: (item: T) => ReactNode;
}

function List<T>(props: ListProps<T>) {
  return <div>{props.items.map(props.renderItem)}</div>;
};
```